# Why is reducing the amount of detail required to remember the location of an object in one's environment adaptively significant?

Tags: adaptation

In Campbell's Biology Chapter 51, question 36 reads:

> Which of the following shows the adaptive significance of cognitive mapping to animals that employ this type of learning?
>
> A) It increases the ability to visually recognize landmarks.
> B) Cognitive maps reduce the amount of detail required to remember the location of an object in the animal's environment.
> C) Animals can locate essential locations in their environment, such as nests, hazards, and feeding areas.
> D) Animals can outmaneuver predators by planning and memorizing getaway routes.
> E) Animals can determine their position relative to landmarks by a triangulation process.
> Answer: B

I answered by saying that Cognitive Mapping is especially important because animals can locate locations essential to its survival (e.g. nests, hazards, and feeding areas), but the answer was B. Why is that more important?

Comment: Hi and welcome. The question you ask here should be self contained. I edited the question; if you don't think it's helpful, please feel free to roll back.